# Can't retrieve key in a dictionary based on value

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
budget = {'Jan-16': '650000', 'Feb-16': '-1100387', 'Mar-16': '-174946', 'Apr-16': '757143', 'May-16': '445709'}
```

When I try to access the value based on key such as:

```
print(budget["Jan-16"])
```

I get the corresponding value i.e. `650000` printed.

But when I try to get the key based on value such as:

```
print(budget.get(650000))
```

I get None printed. I have also tried to get the key value like so:

```
print([for k, v in budget.items() if v == 650000])
```

and nothing gets printed.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `get` method only works with key. So one way is `{v:k for k, v in budget.items()}.get('650000')`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM, it still prints "None" :(

Comment: `650000` is not `'650000'`

Comment: @StephenRauch, when I try ` print(budget.get('650000'))`, it still prints "None"

Comment: `print([k for k, v in budget.items() if v == '650000'])`

Comment: @krithika your this code: `print([for k, v in budget.items() if v == 650000])` prints None bcoz, you are comparing v to numeric 65000 whereas in dict it is stored as string 65000, use `v == '65000'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Code is fine, you just missed to check the value as a stirng as specified in the dictionary.

```
budget = {'Jan-16': '650000', 'Feb-16': '-1100387', 'Mar-16': '-174946', 'Apr- 
16': '757143', 'May-16': '445709'}
for k, v in budget.items():
    if v == '650000':
        print(k)
```

The Output of the above code is : Jan-16

Answer (score 0):

`get` takes *keys* (not values) as arguments--just like `[]` does. However, with `get` you can provide a default value if the key doesn't exist. So `get` won't work for your use.

Your list comprehension just needs to be tweaked a bit to work:

```
[k for k, v in budget.items() if v == '650000']
```

Answer (score 0):

reversing key,values and then we get the key based on values.

```
print ({v:k for k, v in budget.items()}.get('650000'))

#output Jan-16
```